# Action of an Affine Algebraic Group on $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$.

Tags: algebraic-groups

It's well known that any affine algebraic group $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$ can be viewed as a closed subgroup of $\mathbb{G}\mathbb{L}(n,\mathbb{C})$.

But suppose $G$ is an affine algebraic group acting on $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$. Does this imply that the action of $G$ on $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ is equivalent to the action of a closed subgroup of $\mathbb{P}\mathbb{G}\mathbb{L}(3,\mathbb{C})$ on $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$?

Comment: The action is in what category?

Comment: $G$ acts algebraically, the action of $G$ on $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ can be expressed as a morphism

$$
G\times \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2
$$

Comment: I don't know the answer, but what we want is something like: 
$$$$
Let us work over $\Bbb C$ and let $G$ be a linear algebraic group. Then, $G$ is isomorphic as an algebraic group, to a closed subgroup of $\text{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$. Now, let $G$ act morphically on $\Bbb P^2$, so that this induces an action of $\text{GL}_n$ on $\Bbb P^2$, where you want this to be $\text{GL}_3$ I suppose. I think without the standard action of $\text{GL}_3$ on $\Bbb C^3$, we won't induce an action of $\text{PGL}_3$ on $\Bbb P^2$?

Comment: That's one thing I'm not sure about. Does $G$ acting morphically on $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ induce a well-defined action of $G$ on $\mathbb{C}^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. The action gives a morphism of algebraic groups $G\to \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^2)=\mathbb{PGL}(3,\mathbb{C})$. The image is closed and the action is via this closed subgroup.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone reading this question later, a reference for Aut($\mathbb{P}^2)=\mathbb{P}\mathbb{G}\mathbb{L}(3,\mathbb{C})$ is:
https://books.google.com/books?id=3rtX9t-nnvwC&lpg=PA151&ots=XN892EOHsa&dq=Hartshorne%20automorphisms&pg=PA151#v=onepage&q=Hartshorne%20automorphisms&f=false